# Creating New Nodes and Adding Relationships to Existing

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have a small graph, it has 'Parent' nodes (as in Nodes that define the parent of a child) and 'Child' Nodes (the children of said parents).
I have noticed a small problem in the way I create siblings of existing children, and was hoping for some pointers.

```
return client.Cypher
            .Match("(person:Person),(c:IdCounter)")
            .Where((Person person) => person.Email == 'shainefisher@hotmail.com')
            .Create("person-[:PARENT_OF]->(child:Child {name:'fred',dob:timestamp()})")
            .Set("child.timestamp = timestamp()")
            .Set("child.id = c.nextId")
            .Set("c.nextId = c.nextId + 1")
            .Return<Child>("child").Results.ToList();
```

This creates a child that has a parent and creates the relationship, this works perfectly, well, as it was designed to.
This next bit however is where I have a problem:

```
return client.Cypher
            .Match("(child:Child)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(person:Person),(c:IdCounter)")
            .Where((Person person) => person.Email == 'shainefisher@hotmail.com')
            .Create("(child2:Child {name:'derf',dob:timestamp()})")
            .Set("child2.id = c.nextId")
            .Set("c.nextId = c.nextId + 1")
            .Create("(person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child2)")
            .Create("(child2)-[:SIBLING_OF]->(child)")
            .Return<Child>("child2").Results.ToList();
```

Now the first time I run this sibling code I get a second child, linked to the parent, and linked to its sibling, so for most cases this would be fine, but I have 4 children :/

The second time I run the sibling code I get 2 children created (the same child twice with consecutive id's), and they are linked to the parent (PARENT_OF), but 1 new child links to 1 existing child (SIBLING_OF) and the second new child links to the other existing child (SIBLING_OF).
EDIT: This is the Cypher used and the resulting graph after running the sibling code twice: http://ec2-52-89-85-67.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/imagedata/capture.png
I would expect 1 new child to be created, and a SIBLING_OF relationship to be created to the children collected in the original match statement, but that is not what I am getting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(c:IdCounter)")
    .Create("(child2:Child {name:'derf',dob:timestamp()})")
    .Set("child2.id = c.nextId")
    .Set("c.nextId = c.nextId + 1")
    .With("child2")
    .Match("(child:Child)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(person:Person)")
    .Where((Person person) => person.Email == "shainefisher@hotmail.com")
    .CreateUnique("(person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child2)")
    .CreateUnique("(child2)-[:SIBLING_OF]->(child)")
    .Return<Child>("DISTINCT child2");
```

Or at least it creates what I think is what you're after - all the children linked together, and the parent one rel per child.

Comment: You know something, I am going to accept your answer, although mine above did the job I wanted I hadn't actually remembered about the counter for the id column (because I was testing in the browser and deleting a lot of stuff as I did it. So for having all of the code, and in the right order, you get the points. Thanks Chris

Comment: Just a quick comment, the '.CreateUnique("(child2)-[:SIBLING_OF]->(child)")' doesn't actually do anything :( I am working on it now but thought you should be aware: http://ec2-52-89-85-67.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/imagedata/capture2.png

Comment: Really - hmmmm, I'm pretty sure I get all the children 'sibling'd'

Comment: Yes you do, and so do I :/ We were calling the AddChild code instead of the AddSibling, total mistake on our testers part, apologies Chris, sorted.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the issue, it was all a matter of order, and I didn't realise that. In order to do what I wanted I had to use this:

```
create(child2:Child{FirstName:'Sarah',LastName:'Fisher',DateOfBirth:1281222000000,id:118,timestamp:timestamp(),x120:'/',x160:'/',x240:'/',x320:'/',x480:'/',x640:'/',thumbnail:'/',Gender:'Female'})
with child2
match (person:Person{Email:'shainefisher@hotmail.com'})-[:PARENT_OF]-(child:Child)
create unique(person)-[:PARENT_OF{timestamp:timestamp()}]->(child2)
create(child2)-[:SIBLING_OF{timestamp:timestamp()}]->(child)
return person,child,child2
```

As you can see, I now crate the child first, and use WITH to create the relationships, but I also needed to use a CREATE UNIQUE on the PARENT_OF relationship to stop duplication.

Issue resolved, thanks :)

Comment: If only I'd have had better WiFi I'd have answered a couple of hours ago - I've been traipsing around hunting for a spot :)